# How to set the left inset of UICollectionViewListCell text to 0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I created a list by using collection view compositional layout and implemented a default style cell ( please see the picture [UICollectionViewListCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jI3p.png)

There is a space of 20pt on the left side of the text. The space might be different on different screen sizes.

I tried to set its leading inset to 0, but the space won't reflect the value unless the value is bigger than 20

`section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)`

Is there any way to remove the space? or how can I get the space value?

Comment: go for custom cell ? easy way to go with

Comment: Yeah... probably the only solution. Thought it would be able to adjust

Answer (score -1):

**UICollectionViewListCell** has a property called [indentationWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlistcell/3600461-indentationwidth) which is used to configure the indentation width. You might also want to look at [indentationLevel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlistcell/3600460-indentationlevel) property as well.

```swift
let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Item> { cell, indexPath, item in
    cell.indentationWidth = 0
}
```